# calling a confirmation dialog when a option is selected on a context menu

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-dialog

I had the code below that call a dialog when a item on a listview is long clicked.

```
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Projeto clickedProjeto = mAdapter.getItem(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "longClickedItem : "+ clickedProjeto.getName());
        showDeleteDialogConfirmation(clickedProjeto);
        return true;
    }
```

Now I need to call the exact same showDeleteDialogConfirmation() method. But I don't know how to pass the clicked item to the dialog.

Here is the context menu on a selected item. I need to call the dialog on the Excluir statement.

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(item.getTitle()=="Editar"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"calling code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Excluir"){
            //here instead of this toast I need to call the confirmation dialog.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sending sms code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: inside onItemLongClick: 
parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: this method need to to vanish. You can't implement long click and context menu, both have the same functionality. I think. What I need is to call and pass the clickeditem to showdialog confimation inside the onContextItemSelected method.

Comment: don't let the activity to implement OnLongClickListiner do it anonymous  
myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

     @Override
     public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
       View view, int position, long id) {...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. got the index of the item clicked on the list and passed it to the dialog.

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(item.getTitle()=="Editar"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"calling code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Excluir"){
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            int index = info.position;
            Projeto clickedProjeto = mAdapter.getItem(index);
            showDeleteDialogConfirmation(clickedProjeto);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

delete :

> implements OnLongClickListener,

and add this

```
myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                Projeto clickedProjeto = (Projeto)parent.getItem(position);
                Log.d(TAG, "longClickedItem : "+ clickedProjeto.getName());
                showDeleteDialogConfirmation(clickedProjeto);
                return false;
                }

            });
```